Help in understanding Bayesian linear regression.
I am unable to use Bayesian Regression in the following
question. So far I have performed the following calculations:

We have our data points Y, X that are supposed to be generated using the following linear model with added error. The weight (prior) and error follow a Gaussian distribution as shown:
$$Y = \phi(X) \cdot W + \epsilon $$
$$W \sim \mathcal{N} ( \overline{w} ,\Sigma_w)$$
$$\epsilon \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma_n^2.I )$$
Now, we calculate the probability distribution of Y using linearity of GRVs:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
  W \\
  Y
\end{pmatrix} \sim \mathcal{N}\left( 
  \begin{pmatrix}
    \overline{w} \\
    \phi\overline{w}
  \end{pmatrix},
  \begin{pmatrix}
    \Sigma_W & \Sigma_W\phi^T \\
    \phi\Sigma_W & \phi\Sigma_W\phi^T + \sigma_n^2 I
  \end{pmatrix}
\right)
$$
This can in turn be used to calculate the posterior probability $P(W \mid Y)$ that has the following mean and variance:
$$\mu_{\text{post}} = \overline{w}+ \Sigma_{\text{W}} \phi^T (\phi \Sigma_{\text{W}} \phi^T + \sigma_n^2 I)^{-1} (Y - \phi \overline{w})$$
$$\Sigma_{\text{post}} = \Sigma_{\text{W}} - \Sigma_{\text{W}} \phi^T (\phi \Sigma_{\text{W}} \phi^T + \sigma_n^2 I)^{-1} \phi \Sigma_{\text{W}}$$

I am unable to proceed from here and use this knowledge for prediction. Lets say the value to be predicted and evaluation points are $\hat{y}, \hat{x}$ respectively. How do I find $P(\hat{y} \mid \hat{x}, Y)$ ? Thank you.

You can just take the posterior as the new "prior" for your (new) $\hat{y}$, giving us the posterior predictive,  i.e., replacing $\bar w$ and $\Sigma_w$ by $\mu_{\text{post}}$ and $\Sigma_{\text{post}}$, resp.
